# JPanel of JPanels in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to develop a Jpanel of JPanels in Java
the outer JPanel has Layout FlowLayout.LEFT and the inner JPanels have Layout FlowLayout.LEADING 
i added a labels to the inner jpanels 
the should add to the outer panel as a Columns and rows of lables 
but that does not work the labels added to the outer panel as a one row i mean left FowLayout for all

I stored the labels in a linkedlist of linkedlist of labels called board 
here is the code for filling the labels linked list

```
for(int i =0 ; i <7 ;i++)
    {
        LinkedList<JLabel> list =new LinkedList<JLabel>();


        for(int j=0 ; j< 5; j++)
        {
            JLabel lab = new JLabel();
            lab.setIcon(add_icon);
            lab.addMouseListener(listener);
            lab.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));    
            list.add(lab);
        }
        board.add(list);

    }
```

then i added the labels to the outer jpanel called container

Here is the code

```
container.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    for(int i =0 ; i < board.size() ;i++)
    {
        panel =new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        for(int j=0 ; j< board.get(i).size();  j++)
        {
            panel.add(board.get(i).get(j));

        }

        container.add(panel);


        //          
    }
    add(container);

    validate();
    repaint();
```

here is the output it seems that the flow-layout leading does not work

How can i do it ? What should i do to add the labels as rows and columns ?

Comment: So whats your question? What does "*i added a labels to the inner jpanels the should add to the outer panel as a Columns and rows of lables but that does not work the labels added to the outer panel as a one row i mean left FowLayout for all*" mean? Can someone decode that for me?

Comment: Your question is **very** confusing. I'm guessing that English is not your primary language, and that perhaps you used a translation site such as Google translate to help you formulate your question. Please try to clarify your problem better so that we can better understand it.

Comment: Have you considered using a `GridLayout` or a `GridBagLayout` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it can be done by usuing GridBagLayout

```
    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    for(int i =0 ; i < board.size() ;i++)
    {
        panel =new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        c1.fill=GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c1.weighty=-.9;

        //          panel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
        for(int j=0 ; j< board.get(i).size();  j++)
        {               
            c1.gridx = j;
            c1.gridy = 0;
            c1.insets= new Insets(-5,0,0,-5);
            panel.add(board.get(i).get(j),c1);

        }   
        c.weightx =- 5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy =i ;
        c.insets=new Insets(-5,0,-5,0);


        container.add(panel,c);


        //          
    }
    add(container);

    validate();
    repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

`FlowLayout` can't stack components vertically. Use `BoxLayout` instead. Try the following code:

```
container.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++){
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    for(int j = 0; j < board.get(i).size(); j++)
        panel.add(board.get(i).get(j));
    container.add(panel);
}
add(container);
validate();
repaint();
```

Comment: Thank you very much 
its really helpful answer